# The parameter 'text', 'onPressed', 'outlineBtn' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

The code is showing the error that all of the parameters that is text, onPressed, outlineBtn can't have the value null and this problem gets solved when I use the require keyword before them but then it starts showing this error.

Error:

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/Widget/custom_btn.dart:12:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'bool' which excludes null.
bool _outlineBtn = outlineBtn ?? false;
^
lib/Widget/custom_btn.dart:33:11: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
text ?? "Text",

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomBtn extends StatelessWidget {
final String text;
final Function onPressed;
final bool outlineBtn;
CustomBtn(
  {required this.text, required this.onPressed, required this.outlineBtn});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
bool _outlineBtn = outlineBtn ?? false;

return GestureDetector(
  onTap: onPressed(),
  child: Container(
    height: 60.0,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: _outlineBtn ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black,
      border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 2.0,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 24.0,
      vertical: 24.0,
    ),
    child: Text(
      //Create New Account
      text ?? "Text",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: _outlineBtn ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `required` keyword says that the variable must be provided and it cannot be null. In you case `outlineBtn` can never be null.

```
bool _outlineBtn = outlineBtn ?? false;
```

To fix this you can either omit the null check or omit the `required` keyword and change your variable to nullable.

```
final String? text;
final Function? onPressed;
final bool? outlineBtn;
```